# How do I grant access to a user/group to use BigQuery in GCP console?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery dataset and I wish to grant read access on that dataset to a Google group called somegroup@myorg.com. I have granted that group the READER role on the dataset as proved by this command:

```
$ bq show myproject98765:mydataset
Dataset myproject98765:mydataset

   Last modified                         ACLs                                     Labels               
 ----------------- ------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------- 
  28 Nov 12:57:34   Owners:                                          
                      projectOwners                                   
                    Readers:                                                                           
                      somegroup@myorg.com
```

However, members of that group are not able to access the BigQuery interface at https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery. When they visit https://console.cloud.google.com/ the project ("myproject98765") is not available in the project picker.

I assume I have to grant a role to that group that enables its members to access project myproject98765, what is the least permissive role I can grant that will allow those members to access https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery and nothing else

Answer (score 2):

OK, figured this out. Members of that group do not need to be granted any permissions on myproject98765. If they have access to the dataset (which, as I said above, they do) then its sufficient to login to console.cloud.google.com and query that dataset from *any* project, they do not have to have explicit access to the project in which the dataset resides.

In case anyone cares, we deploy permissions using terraform. The terraform code in this case is:

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "ds" {
  project .     = "myproject98765"
  dataset_id    = "mydataset"
  location      = "EU"

  access {
    role           = "READER"
    group_by_email = "somegroup@myorg.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI: If the needs of that group can be met by a website that you control instead of BigQuery Web UI, then have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59098568/12005425) answer.